# ISO-8859-1 utf-8 problems in JAVA

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I'm getting Chinese characters with **getBytes** method and I have to send it to other side by encoding with **UTF-8**, But other side is getting garbled values. How to solve this problem, I really appreciate your help, Thanks!

I'm getting parameter as follows:

```
String remark = new String(request.getParameter("remark").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8");
```

Before sending it to other side I'm encoding it with **URLEncoder**

```
URLEncoder.encode(remark, "utf-8");
```

Comment: "ISO-8859-1" and Chinese chars?? You probably need to do some `URLEncoder.decode`

Comment: Encoding ISO-8859-1 bytes with UTF8 doesn't make any sense. request.getParameter() already returns a String. Leave it as it is.